# If $\operatorname{Char} K \neq 2$ then all bilinear form $b:V\times V \rightarrow K$ skew-symmetric is alternating

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$. If $\operatorname{Char}K\neq 2$,
> then each skew-symmetric bilinear form $b:V\times V\rightarrow K$
> is alternating.

Let $b$ be a skew-symmetric bilinear form and let $B$ be
a matrix associated with $b$. Since $b$ is skew-symmetric then
we have $b(u_i,u_j)=-b(u_j,u_i)$ and then
for the entries $b_{ij}$ of $B$ we have that
$b_{ij}u_iu_j+b_{ji}u_ju_i=0$ and hence $b(w,w)=\sum_i b_{ii}w_i^2$

But here I'm stuck, is the above okay? And how can I continue?

Comment: Or i just have to say that $b(w,w)=-b(w,w)=0$ because $0$ its the only element in a field which satisfies that its equal to its inverse?

Comment: Is $K$ another name for $\mathbb F?$ How about you give a little more context what all the letters mean?

Comment: Oh yes sorry I already corrected it

Comment: You should still say what $V$ is, and that $K$ is a field.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews done

Comment: @OlgaGonzalez, I have corrected your text slightly. I hope I have not distorted its meaning.

Comment: The idea in your comment is pretty much spot on - skew-symmetric forms satisfy $b(x, y) + b(y, x) = 0$, so in particular you get $2 b(x, x) = 0$. Provided the characteristic of the field is not 2, you can divide by 2 to get $b(x, x) = 0$, hence the form is alternating.